# ¿Por qué no se puede visualizar mi web en parís?

Tags: html5, dns

el siguiente problema es que estoy trabajando con **GoogleAds** y para que mis anuncios funciones necesito pasar una serie de pruebas en mi web. Pero tengo un pequeño error que la verdad después de buscar en varias paginas tanto en español como en ingles no encontré una solución.

Al poner mi web (https://metalicasrosales.com/) en esta herramienta (https://www.uptrends.com/tools/uptime). Me sale que en **Paris** no carga, da un error: DNS Lookup Error.

Ya he revisado el DNS de mi host y nada. Está todo bien...

Muchas gracias, saludos a todos.

Comment: ¿Te has fijado que todos los servidores DNS de tu dominio son la misma IP? Es decir, aunque tienen nombres diferentes, todos resuelven a `162.215.253.15` (precisamente la misma IP que aloja tu página web). ¿Has probado a usar un servicio gratuito de DNS secundario en vez de hacer ese tipo de "trampas"?

Comment: No. No tenía idea, así me vino el host configurado. Supongo qué ese debe ser el problema. Cuando te refieres a "trampas" , es algo malo?

Comment: Sí, ya que se supone que los servidores DNS secundarios deberían estar, a ser posible, en una red diferente. En caso de no ser posible, al menos en una máquina distinta. El registro SOA de tu dominio que se usa para el TTL de respuestas negativas es de 86400 segundos (1 día), así que si hubo un error de resolución DNS probablemente hasta mañana no puedas probar de nuevo. El mensaje "DNS Lookup Error" no especifica si fue tiempo de espera agotado o si fue una respuesta negativa... habrá que esperar por si es lo segundo.

Comment: Por último, si es tiempo agotado, podría un problema en la ruta entre el nodo de París que hace la prueba y tu servidor. Yo, personalmente, te recomendaría hacer uso de un CDN gratuito como [cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com). Ellos te proporcionan un servicio DNS redundante y distribuido real sin necesidad de activar las opciones de CDN, sólo usando su [servicio DNS](https://www.cloudflare.com/dns/). Si activas el soporte CDN entonces mejor que mejor.

Comment: Gracias Oscar, voy a usar cloudflare. Porque la verdad mi proveedor de servidor no me da respuesta...